# I'm using twilio 6.0.2 and Client doesn't work

Tags: python, twilio

```
from twilio.rest import Client

# Your Account SID from twilio.com/console
account_sid = "`enter code here`"
# Your Auth Token from twilio.com/console
auth_token  = "`enter code here`"

client = Client(account_sid, auth_token)

message = client.messages.create(
    to="`enter code here`", 
    from_="`enter code here`",
    body="Hello from Python!")

print(message.sid)
```

Error that pops:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "C:\Users\mediamarkt2\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\sendtext.py",
>   line 1, in 
>       from twilio.rest import Client ImportError: cannot import name 'Client'

I'm using 6.0. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What makes you believe that twilio is installed in your Python?

Comment: As @lit is also hinting at, if you type `pip list` in your terminal, do you see twilio (6.X.X) ?

Comment: When i import twilio and print out (twilio.__version__) there is no error

Comment: Yes twilio 6.X.X shows up, it shows twilio(6.3.dev0)

Comment: Where did you get that version from? The latest alpha release I can see is 6.2.0-alpha-1 but I would recommend using the official 6.2.0
It doesn't look like 6.3.dev0 is an official up-to-date version

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

If you find you have installed version 6.3.dev0, then you have an out of date version I'm afraid. 6.3.dev0 was never an official release.

The latest official release for [Twilio Python](https://www.twilio.com/docs/libraries/python) is now [6.3.0](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/twilio). Make sure you are using one of these releases and not the `dev0` tag, then your code will work.

Let me know if that helps at all.